In CKEditor, Heading and Lists(todo,mathlist,...) are not applying simultaneously
When i enter any Letter/Sentence in CKEditor, then make it as any List and here after selecting the List the Letter/Sentence Heading is getting change from Paragraph to Choose Heading.
List are not accepting a Heading
When i enter any Letter/Sentence in CKEditor, then make it as any List, that List should accepts as a Heading
enter image description here
Code :
 requiredToolbarItems: any = [
    'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline', ,
    'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList', '|',
    'undo', 'redo',
    'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontColor',  'fontBackgroundColor', '|',
    'alignment', '|',
    // 'fullscreen','fontBackgroundColor',
  ]
  optionaltoolbarItems: any = ['heading', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'code', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'removeFormat', '|', 'link', 
  // 'blockQuote'
   'insertTable', '|', 'sourceEditing', 'MathType', 'ChemType']

 createCkeditor() {
    CKEDITOR.ClassicEditor.create(this.myEditor.nativeElement, {

      toolbar: {
        items: this.requiredToolbarItems.concat(this.isShowLimitedOptions == 'true' ? [] : this.optionaltoolbarItems),
        shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
      },
      list: {
        properties: {
          styles: true,
          startIndex: true,
          reversed: true
        }
      },
      // https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/headings.html#configuration
      heading: {
        options: [
          { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
          { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
          { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
          { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Heading 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' },
          { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Heading 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
          { model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Heading 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5' },
          { model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Heading 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6' }
        ]
      },
      placeholder: 'Type here',
      fontFamily: {
        options: [
          'default',
          'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
          'Courier New, Courier, monospace',
          'Georgia, serif',
          'Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif',
          'Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif',
          'Times New Roman, Times, serif',
          'Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif',
          'Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif'
        ],
        supportAllValues: true
      },
      fontSize: {
        options: [10, 12, 14, 'default', 18, 20, 22],
        supportAllValues: true
      },
      htmlSupport: {
        allow: [
          {
            name: /.*/,
            attributes: true,
            classes: true,
            styles: true
          }
        ]
      },
      htmlEmbed: {
        showPreviews: true
      },

      link: {
        decorators: {
          addTargetToExternalLinks: true,
          defaultProtocol: 'https://',
          toggleDownloadable: {
            mode: 'manual',
            label: 'Downloadable',
            attributes: {
              download: 'file'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      mention: {
        feeds: [
          {
            marker: '@',
            feed: [
              '@apple', '@bears', '@brownie', '@cake', '@cake', '@candy', '@canes', '@chocolate', '@cookie', '@cotton', '@cream',
              '@cupcake', '@danish', '@donut', '@dragée', '@fruitcake', '@gingerbread', '@gummi', '@ice', '@jelly-o',
              '@liquorice', '@macaroon', '@marzipan', '@oat', '@pie', '@plum', '@pudding', '@sesame', '@snaps', '@soufflé',
              '@sugar', '@sweet', '@topping', '@wafer'
            ],
            minimumCharacters: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      mathTypeParameters: {
        service: 'https://www.wiris.net/demo/editor',
        editorParameters: { language: 'en' },
        textPartLanguage: ['en']
      },
      removePlugins: [
        'CKBox',
        'CKFinder',
        'EasyImage',
        'RealTimeCollaborativeComments',
        'RealTimeCollaborativeTrackChanges',
        'RealTimeCollaborativeRevisionHistory',
        'PresenceList',
        'Comments',
        'TrackChanges',
        'TrackChangesData',
        'RevisionHistory',
        'Pagination',
        'WProofreader',
        'SlashCommand',
        'Template',
        'DocumentOutline',
        'FormatPainter',
        'TableOfContents',
        'ImageToolbar',
        'ImageStyle',
        'ImageResize',
        'Autoformat'  
      ],

      // commands: {
      //   CustomButton: {
      //     // Label for the button
      //     label: 'Media Handler',

      //     // Icon for the button
      //     icon: './assets/images/icon/FocalPoint-Icon-1.png',

      //     // Function to execute when the button is clicked
      //     command: function (editor) {
      //       // Your custom logic goes here
      //       alert('Custom button clicked!');
      //     },
      //   }
      // }
    }).then(editor => {
      this.editor = editor;
      this.updateEditor.emit(editor);
      // this.updateEditor.subscribe(() => {
      //   console.log("test")
      // });
      if (this.editorValue) {
        editor.setData(this.editorValue);
        this.editor = this.editorValue;
      }
      if (this.fromMini) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const mathTypeButton = editor.ui.view.toolbar.element.querySelector('button[data-cke-tooltip-text="Insert a math equation - MathType"]');
          const chemTypeButton = editor.ui.view.toolbar.element.querySelector('button[data-cke-tooltip-text="Insert a chemistry formula - ChemType"]');
          if (mathTypeButton && chemTypeButton) {
            mathTypeButton.style.display = 'none';
            chemTypeButton.style.display = 'none';
          }
        }, 0)
      }
      // editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
      //   return new UploadAdapter(loader,this.sharedService);
      // };
      editor.ui.getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(
        editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
        editor.ui.getEditableElement()
      );

      const imageButton = document.createElement('button');
      imageButton.setAttribute('data-cke-tooltip-text', 'Insert Image');
      imageButton.classList.add('ck');
      imageButton.classList.add('ck-button');
      imageButton.classList.add('ck-off');
      imageButton.innerHTML = '<span class="ck-button"><img  src="./assets/images/icon/addimage.jpg" /></span>';

      imageButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    //     if (this.editor) {
    //       const selection = this.editor.model.document.selection;
    //      console.log(selection)
    // if (selection.hasOwnRange) { debugger;

    //   const selectedRange = selection.getFirstRange();

    //   // Check if the selected range is valid
    //   if (selectedRange) {
    //     let selectedText = '';

    //     // Iterate through the selected range to collect text
    //     for (const item of selectedRange.getItems()) {
    //       if (item.is('text')) {
    //         selectedText += item.data;
    //       }
    //     }

    //     console.log(selectedText);
    //   }
    // }
    //     }
        await this.handleImageInsert(editor);
      });

      const customButton = document.createElement('button');
      customButton.setAttribute('data-cke-tooltip-text', 'Media Handler');
      customButton.classList.add('ck');
      customButton.classList.add('ck-button');
      customButton.classList.add('ck-off');
      customButton.innerHTML = '<span class="ck-button"><img  src="./assets/images/icon/videoaudio.png" /></span>';

      customButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        // Handle the click event for your custom button
        await this.handleMediaHandler(editor);
      });

      const documentCustomButton = document.createElement('button');
      documentCustomButton.setAttribute('data-cke-tooltip-text', 'Insert Document');
      documentCustomButton.classList.add('ck');
      documentCustomButton.classList.add('ck-button');
      documentCustomButton.classList.add('ck-off');
      documentCustomButton.innerHTML = '<span class="ck-button"><img  src="./assets/images/icon/assignment_black_16px.png" /></span>';

      // Create a hidden file input
      const fileInput = document.createElement('input');
      fileInput.type = 'file';
      fileInput.style.display = 'none';

      documentCustomButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        fileInput.click();
      });

      // Listen for file selection in the hidden file input
      fileInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
        this.handleFileSelection(editor, fileInput.files[0]);
      });



      const toolbarContainer = editor.ui.view.toolbar.element;
      const itemsContainer = toolbarContainer.querySelector('.ck-toolbar__items');
      if (this.isShowLimitedOptions == 'false') {
        itemsContainer.appendChild(customButton);
        itemsContainer.appendChild(imageButton)
      }
      itemsContainer.appendChild(documentCustomButton);


    })

      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });

  }

